# Can you call the Marketing Cloud Fuel/REST API to effect a master unsubscribe?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel

I have a use case where I need call a Marketing Cloud API from Sales Cloud Apex code to effect a master unsubscribe.  I can see how to do that using the SOAP API but that is painful as it requires using the WSDLtoApex process which creates massive Apex classes which impacts code coverage.  Is it possible to call the REST API to effect a master unsubscribe?  There are plenty of examples like toggling the HTML email yes/no attribute, but there are not example of changing the value of the subscriber status based on the ID of Contact.  Thanks  Richard

Comment: We have "solved" this by created custom Apex classes which wrap the SOAP API.  It would have been much easier if there was a REST API call to do this.  Or if the managed package class Unsubscribe() method used named credentials rather requiring the sales cloud user to have already authenticated into marketing cloud.  At least we have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you are referring to; you are looking at `/contacts/v1/contacts` route with a PATCH method. Unfortunately, you can only use this to modify the email address or HTML boolean attribute. You will need to use the SOAP API to update the Subscriber status.